# Is there a way to make var a compile-time error in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, var

We're updating to us Java 17.
Is there a way in Maven to make it so that using `var` creates a compile-time error without compiling for an older version of java?
In other words, I don't want to have to tell Maven to compile for 1.8 or the like.

I'd also prefer not to use an IDE centric solution since we don't all use the same IDE.

Comment: I don't think you can selectively turn off language features like that. IMO a sane solution is to have that kind of check as an external quality tool separately (something like checkstyle, errorprone, sonarqube, ...).

Comment: *I don't want to have to tell Maven to compile for 1.8* even if that does exactly what you want? ok...

Comment: @Antoniossss: it would also turn off all other language features after that, like switch expressions, instanceof pattern matching, text blocks, record types, ...

Comment: and those features will work just fine on lower Java versions???

Comment: @Antoniossss ??? no, they would not, which is likely why the OP doesn't want to compile with Java 8.

Comment: What is the point then to have compile time error for 1 feature due to "it no beeing compatible backwards" but keep all the others in place (which are not backwards compatible neither) ?? :)

Comment: @Antoniossss: I think you made up the "backwards compatible" argument on your own, because I don't see anyone else mentioning it. OP could have any number of reasons to dislike this specific feature (maybe they've found that code becomes less readable without the explicit type, ...). If backwards compatibility was the goal, then turning off that one feature alone would be silly, agreed.

Comment: The question is why is it a problem to use `var ..` (type inference).. ? Exists since JDK10... So if you only allow JDK8 feature (you should use `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` but that prevents the usage of several other language features.. If it's about readability you should go via checkstyle or SonarQube (Static code analyzer)... but in the mean time newer versions suggest the usage also the IDE's make suggestings in that direction. If you like to remove all usage of `var ..` that can be done via IntelliJ IDEA (https://youtu.be/ujGsLZjrz6c)

Comment: Why do you not want to use `var`?  A good IDE can tell you anyway and your code gets shorter.

Comment: "Why do I want this?" seems to be the question of the day. Answer: The psudo-soft-typing borrowed from other languages is simply very easy to pollute. Strong typing is easier to read and easier to maintain in the long run. I prefer strong-typed languages and don't want soft-types in the Java code I maintain. Old adage of "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should." Not everyone will agree, obviously, but that is the reason. At the end of the day, I'm asking *how* to do it. If you personally like soft typing in Java, I'm not telling you to stop using it.

Comment: @ScrappyDev You seem to either be mistaken about how this feature works, or mistaken about what "strong typing" (or soft typing) means.  A variable declared with `var` is exactly as strongly typed as one with a manifest type; it merely means that the compiler figures out the static type for you, but it still has a static type and the compiler performs exactly the same static type checking.

Comment: @ScrappyDev In any case, no, you cannot pick and choose which language features you want the compiler to support.  You can use style-checking tools like `CheckStyle` to enforce a personal style guide if you want.

Comment: @ScrappyDev having `var` will have exactly the same effect like explicitly typed variable as long as "the right side of assignment" is of obvious and known type. This is just a shortcut like diamont operator is when you actually know what should be there. it is NOT declaration of variabla that can be anything anywhere (its not hidden `Object obj;` declaration). So I agree with Brian. @Joahim you are right about me making up requiremets and mention regarding compilation to 1.8 (proposed by the OP) as a solution put me of tracks.

Comment: @ScrappyDev If it was not a dream I even recall Sonar encourage to use of `var` in some specific scenarios claiming that code readability goes higher. In come cases I can agree with that as `var list=new ArrayList<String>()` is not confusing at all right? But thats offtopic actually.

Comment: @BrianGoetz That's why I called it Psudo-soft-typing. The compiler picks the type it compiles it to rather than you.

Comment: @ScrappyDev There's an actual name for this: type inference.  Type inference has been used in statically typed languages since the 80s, and Java has used type inference in other contexts since Java 5.  It's not pseudo-anything, or soft-anything.

Comment: @BrianGoetz - That's just semantics. And not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 5):

In general consider using static analyzer of your code that runs as a plugin. You can define a rule to fail the build once `var` is observed in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Checkstyle's [IllegalType](https://checkstyle.org/config_coding.html#IllegalType) check. Checkstyle has [a Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/).

The relevant part of the XML config would look like:

```
...
<module name="IllegalType">
  <property name="illegalClassNames" value="var"/>
</module>
...
```

Bit funny that the property is called "illegal**ClassNames**", but I tested and it worked, [as Checkstyle's maintainer said it would](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/8978#issuecomment-737306564).

Comment: One other thing we're looking at is SonarQube rules, but I like this a bit more since it can happen at build-time.

Answer (score 3):

Like Mark said, this is a job for a static code analyzer. I would use [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/), which can easily be [integrated with Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/).

You can use the [MatchXpath](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#MatchXpath) module to achieve what you want. In fact, the example on the website does the opposite, requiring that all variables use `var`. To get the result you want, you should be able to simply invert the second part of the rule:

```
<module name="MatchXpath">
  <property name="query" value="//VARIABLE_DEF[./ASSIGN/EXPR/LITERAL_NEW
          and (./TYPE/IDENT[@text='var'])]"/>
  <message key="matchxpath.match" value="'var' not allowed"/>
</module>
```